# How to remove vertical space in table columns?

Tags: tables

I am using the template from the below link

https://digital-library.theiet.org/files/IET_Author-doublecolumn-submission.zip

The code for constructing the table is

```
\documentclass{cta-author}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{booktabs}
 \begin{document}
 \begin{table}[]
    \centering
    \processtable{Comparison of performance indices for different cases \label{Table2}}
    {\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}|c|c|c|c|c|@{}}
            \toprule 
             &  A             & B              & C               & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{}     \\ 
            \midrule
            \multirow{3}{*}{p = 2}                                             & 0.5               & 
            0.01               & 0.29               & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{I}  \\ \cmidrule{2-5} 
            & 0.56                 & 4.7                 & 2.7                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|} 
           {J}  \\ \cmidrule{2-5} 
            & 8.2                  & 2.6                 & 1.4                 & \multicolumn{1}{c|} 
       {K} \\ 
            \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}}{}
    \end{table}

    \end{document}
```

[image: Table]

I want complete single vertical lines for all the columns. In the table image attached here, the vertical  lines of the columns are broken in each row. What changes shall I make in the code to ensure a single vertical line in the columns?

Comment: `booktabs` with commands like `\midrule` is not made for vertical rules.

Comment: What shall I use in place of \midrule, \cmidrule, \bottomrule

Comment: (1) change all the *horizontal* rules by `\hline`  or (2) very very very much better, remove all the *vertical* lines and left "as is"  the `booktabs` rules.

Comment: I have replaced \midrule by \hline. How shall I replace \cmidrule{2-5}?

Comment: @ShiS - How about `\cline{2-5}`. Do also please check out [What are good learning resources for a LaTeX beginner?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/11/5001)

Comment: The \cline{2-5} does not work with the template given in the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that (a) gets rid of all vertical lines, thereby giving the table a much more open "look", (b) gets rid of code clutter, such as the meaning `\multicolumn` wrappers around the cells in the final column, and replaces the mistaken `@{\extracolsep{\fill}}` directive with `@{}` since a `tabular` rather than a `tabular*` environment is in use.

A general comment: Just because one can find lots of LaTeX code out there on the Internet doesn't mean that the code is of high quality or, more modestly, bug-free.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{multirow} % not needed
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
  \centering
  % (don't know how '\processtable' is defined, hence commented out:)
  % \processtable{Comparison of performance indices for different cases}
  \label{Table2}
    \begin{tabular}{@{} l cccc @{}}     \toprule 
             &  A   & B    & C    & D \\ \midrule
             & 0.5  & 0.01 & 0.29 & I \\ \cmidrule{2-5} 
       p = 2 & 0.56 & 4.7  & 2.7  & J \\ \cmidrule{2-5} 
             & 8.2  & 2.6  & 1.4  & K \\ \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
 \end{table}
 \end{document}
```

Comment: Is it possible to add 3 vertical lines: at the leftmost end of the table, rightmost end of the table and at the beginning of the second column (after p = 2)? However,  the command `\cline{2-5}` cannot be used in the template given in question

Comment: @Mico +1 for excellent edit-- my education increased